# how i should need to write method to use it anywhere in a class

Tags: java, android

Still i am calling startUpload(position); method in getView(...) {} method, but now i wanna call it in

```
   loginbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {....}
```

Like this, but always i am getting **position cannot be resolved to a variable**
so here i want to know how i should need to write method to use it anywhere in a class:

```
             loginbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    SaveData();     
                    alertDialog.dismiss();  
                    startUpload(position);
                    }
```

below is the method, startUpload(...){...}

```
//Upload
        public void startUpload(final int position) {      
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            View v = lstView.getChildAt(position - lstView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                            // Show ProgressBar
                            ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                            progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            //  Status  
                            TextView status = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.ColStatus);
                            status.setText("Uploading..");

                            new UploadFileAsync().execute(String.valueOf(position));   
                        }
                    }); 
                }
            };
            new Thread(runnable).start();
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to declare method globally in Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421555/how-to-declare-method-globally-in-class)

Comment: Asking the same question twice makes no sense on SO. The `startUpload()` method is no help here. Show some more context of `loginbutton.setOnClickListener(...);` Although the error message is pretty self explanatory: You're trying to use `position` where it is out of scope. If it's in scope, it needs to be `final` in order to be accessible by the inner anonymous class.

Comment: in `onClick`, what is `position` supposed to be?

Comment: @jlordo but i am not getting correct answer buddy

Comment: I think they are in separated classes, just add a references to the class which your action is, then in onclick method call the method by the reference you got

Comment: @AbrahimNeil: That's because you are not showing us the relevant code, which you have been asked for a few times now. Also, the correct answer is already in my comment above.

Comment: exactly @jlordo is right, or you can create a class that implements/extends the desired member, and also pass the everything needs to work with, then create an instance and pass it to the button instead of inline declaration

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following sintax.

```
loginbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SaveData();     
        alertDialog.dismiss();  
        startUpload(OldUploadActivity.this.position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhm.. indeed position is not a field, I didn't notice that, sorry. I'll run some experiment and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `final int position` as a parameter to `onPrepareDialog()` as well; just like you're passing it to the `getView()` method. Also, update the line of code from where you're actually invoking this method from by passing the actual position value.

```
public void onPrepareDialog(final int position, int id, Dialog dialog) {
```

Comment: tried dialog buttons not responding, can you show me the exact code, which you think i should write

Comment: What value are you passing as position to getView() or startUpload()? Pass the same to onPrepareDialog().

Comment: actually buddy i am getting confuse, i have posted whole code, can you show me how my onPrepareDialog() should look....?

Comment: Change the method signature as in my answer. Then "pass" position value as you've done for getView *from where you're calling the method.* The code you've shared doesn't show how your getView and startUpload are getting called. Find them and call onPrepareDialog like that.